# zookeeper: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jute/InputArchive

Tags: apache-zookeeper

upgrading zookeeper from already installed zookeeper-3.4.12 to zookeeper-3.5.7. Getting below error while start the zookeeper service

```
    Started Zookeeper.
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jute/InputArchive
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.<init>(FileTxnSnapLog.java:162)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:124)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:106)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:64)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:128)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:82)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jute.InputArchive
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Apr 06 07:40:30 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa java[15504]: ... 6 more
Apr 06 07:40:31 ad-fn5x-etl.41web.qa systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```